# Remove all UNLESS word into large bands dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, sentiment-analysis

I have this pandas dataframe with this structure in Google Colaboratory:

```
root
 |-- content: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score: string (nullable = true)

+----------------------+------+
| content              |score |
+----------------------+------+
| Wow                  |  5   |
+----------------------+------+
| dfghjja              |  2   |
+----------------------+------+
| udsx nnnn 012mmmm    |  5   |
+----------------------+------+
| okkk                 |  4   |
+----------------------+------+
| wefcxz               |  3   |
+----------------------+------+
```

The total number of row is **2'534'500**. 
The data frame is about review of application, where content is the text of review and score is the rating.
I'm doing a sentiment analysis, so I need to clean up the text, removing all the words that are useless for my analysis, such as: **wefcxz** or **dfghjja** or **udsx nnnn 012mmmm**. How can I remove this unless words?
In the data frame there are also other text more complete such that "Unable to update my whatsapp". 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same answer as yesterday. Use `pyenchant` and `difflib`. If you want help prove you've been looking for a solution...

Comment: @Corralien Yes is the same of yesterday...I deleted it to reformulate it better

Comment: @Corralien pyenchant is not useful to me as it returns False even to strings that are still in English such as "so frustrating i been trying to upgrade my whatsapp for the past 3 month now i could not so frustrating". In this way I would go to eliminate a lot of reviews

Comment: What is the difference between 'okkkk' and 'dfghjja'. In fact, none. The two words does not exist. I think you have to spell check before to remove content unless you have another idea?